# How does one implement the asynchronous pattern in a child Logic App?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Logic Apps support calling other Logic Apps with a special action:

[image: Logic App action]

They support something they call the "asynchronous pattern" through this option:

[image: Logic App asynchronous pattern option]

where the called Logic App returns a 202 (Accepted) and the calling Logic App will implicitly poll the same trigger URL until completion is signalled using 200 (OK).

How are you supposed to implement this pattern in the called Logic App? I can send a response, but once that's happened, I can't send a response again. Or can I? If so; how? How do you specify the polling URL?

Answer (score 2):

In the response action, you could enable 'Asynchronous Response'. See the dialog below

[[image: dialog box image]]